# Inner DIV makes outer DIV grows - How to avoid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you might have seen in my previous posts, I'm working on a HTML implementation of the Office Ribbon to be used in web applications.

Currently the ribbon is looking like this:

[image]

Now, I've created a dropdown menu, so when you click on items a dropdown menu is showed and that looks like the following:

[image]

As you see the space that the item "New Items" takes does grow when the dropdown is visible.
I would like to achieve the following:

1. The "New Items" menu entry stays the same width if it's showed or not.

In the HTML, the dropdown item is part of the menu item.
Here's the HTML to make it clear:

```
<div class="icon bigicon">
    <img src="Resources/Icons/MailNewItemMenu.png" />
    <div class="label">
        New<br/>Items
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menucontents">
            <ul class="nopadding nomargin">
                <li>E-Mail Message</li>
                <li>Appointment</li>
                <li>Meeting</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Task</li>
                <li>E-Mail Message Using</li>
                <li>More items</li>
                <li>Lync Meeting</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is the following (I know it isn't best practice, I'm going to adapt that one):

```
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon { text-align: center; display: inline-block; padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; vertical-align: top; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .bigicon { height: 70px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon { padding-top: 0px; height: 24px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon:hover { background-color: #cde6f7; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon:active { background-color: #92C0E0; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .label { line-height: 16px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon { display: inline-block; padding-right: 5px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon IMG { vertical-align: middle; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon .label { display: inline-block; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .menu { position: relative; top: -1px; left: 1px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;}
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .menu .menucontents { padding: 1px; position: relative; z-index: 100; background-color: white; left: -4px; border-top: 1px solid #C6C6C6; border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C6C6; background-image: linear-gradient(#C6C6C6, #C6C6C6), linear-gradient(#C6C6C6, #C6C6C6); background-size:1px 100%; background-position: 0 0, 100% 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .menu .menucontents > ul li { text-align: left; list-style: none; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .menu .menucontents > ul li:hover { background-color: #cde6f7; }
```

In case you are interested in the project, here it is: https://github.com/Kevin-De-Coninck/OfficeWebControls

There's a JsFiddle here that can be used to check it. In the fiddle the down arrow is not showed (don't know why), but if I do the trick with the position absolute and relative, the down arrow is not displayed anymore.

Can someone have a look at the JsFiddle and maybe correct it?
Thanks in advance: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/P5Bnc/3/

Kind regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set `position:relative` on the div with the `icon` class.

Then set `position:absolute` on the div with the `menu` class.

Also you can set the `top:80px` to position it better.

**EDIT:**

here's a fiddle applying my changes to the fiddle you provided: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5Bnc/4/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the explanation, but none of the above solutions is working. I've taked the advice here and here's is JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/P5Bnc/

Comment: I've edited my answer with a modified version of your fiddle. check it out and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Hey, thats already something very promising. I managed to achieve the same, but the problem is that now in the dropdown "Email Message" is on 2 lines (the very first entry) and I don't know why. If you can provide me with a solution to that, I will be very thankfull :-)

Comment: Again thank you very much by my "Down" arrow after the text "New items" is removed and I don't like using min-width. Isn't there another solution to just say 100% or something similar?

Comment: for the arrow, just remove the `menu` class from the `<i>` tag. That's from javascript as I see. And why isn't min-width good enough ?

Comment: if the position is absolute then the drop div will not expand. you have to tell it to expand, to respect your desire.

Comment: Min width is not good because the text is not fixed and can change. If the text changes it might appear again on 2 lines so is there an easy solution?

Comment: this is the only way I know, the width of the menu div is retained from it's parent, and it is not in the normal sequence of elements since it is positioned absolute. So the width has to be manually set.

Comment: Ok thanks for your clarification. I will implement it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no live example, I can only provide guidelines:

- add `position: relative` to `.icon` or `.bigicon`
- change `.icon .menu` to `position:absolute`
- fix the positioning of the dropdown by using `top:100%` and appropriate `margin-top`, since it will now be positioned absolutely

If you create an isolated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it would be easier to provide a specific solution for your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set **position:absolute;** and **z-index:999;** in  **class="menu"**
this bring your (div class="menu") to front

after this you can set (div class="menu") position as you like ( left: 20px; top:100px; ) or whatever you want